# C# I can't view pictures in html file

Tags: c#, html, image

I have images folder inside my project. I am viewing the html file but cannot view the pictures. I didn't understand why I couldn't reach the picture.

My Html Code

```
<p><img src="/images/aboutus_index.png" width="1020"/></p>
```

[My Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdveo.png)

my c # code to read the html file.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("htmldeneme.index.html"));
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: `src="~/images/aboutus_index.png"` try adding the `~` at the beginning. Also I don't think it is necessary to put an `img` tag inside of a `p` tag

Comment: I've tried. I still can't view it. <img src="~/images/aboutus_index.png" width="1020"/>

Comment: When I add a web image link it shows up without any problem. The problem is cannot access the file path in my project.

Comment: What if you just don't use the / at the front, and make sure to include the images folder in the project output?